# do I have to detach events from deleted Elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'am loading via Ajax some elements to div and add some events like this:

```
$('.zoom-container').on('touchmove click scroll mousedown mousewheel', zoom.userEvent)
```

my html:

```
<div id="Overlay"></div>
```

my code to create some content:

```
$(".full_screen_icon").on({        //delegation
   click: function(evt) {
        var my_html ="zoom  prtty▲thngs";
        var colWidth= $(".block-wrap[data-colspan='2']").eq(0).outerWidth() || "300px";
            //content div erstellen
            $("<div>", {
            id: "detail_content",
                css: {
                    height:colWidth,
                    width:colWidth,
                    "margin-top":-colWidth/2,
                    "margin-left":-colWidth/2
                },
                html: my_html
            })
            .appendTo("#Overlay");

        //content holen via ajax
        $.get("http://www.yxz.de/products/"+ t +".php", function( html ) {
            $("#detail_content").html(html);
        }, 'html');
    }
       .. add zoom-container with some events like above

});
```

to close the overlay i do this:

```
$("#Overlay").click(function (e) {
    $(this).find('#detail_content').empty().remove();       
});
```

I allways thought that, if I remove the element with the attached events that the events are gone too.

But here I'am loading on click the same named elements and attach the same named events.

I see that the events are still there after removing the div.element. Is this an issue in my code or is this the normal behaviour?

**I'am insecure now. Are the events deleted with the element or not?**

Comment: How are you seeing that the events are still there? What does that even mean? You're probably confusing events with event handlers.

Comment: zoom.userEvent adds a click event to an element.
If I delete the element and add in again the click event is double.

Comment: Omar: you are right. I didn't see that before

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly all you need to do is to create a delegate listener instead of a regular one.

```
$("#Overlay").on('touchmove click scroll mousedown mousewheel', '.zoom-container', zoom.userEvent);
```

This way you won't be attaching a new event listener every time a new element appears.